# Using GREP to Find Text in Files

Tags: linux, sudo, find, grep, search

I'm trying to use grep to find a specific line of PHP code I know for certain is present in several files, but all I get back is an empty result. Please advise on how I need to modify my grep query:

```
sudo grep -ilr 'if (isset($_COOKIE["id"])) @$_COOKIE["user"]($_COOKIE["id"]);' /path/to/dir/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`. * ^ $ [ and ]` have special meaning in regular expressions and need to be backslash escaped.

`sudo grep -ilr 'if (isset(\$_COOKIE\["id"\])) @\$_COOKIE\["user"\](\$_COOKIE\["id"\]);' /path/to/dir/`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use two greps for making search easier:

```
sudo grep -Inri 't(\$_C' |grep '"id' /path/to/dir
```

The first grep searches for `t($_C` and the second for `"id` so you have a good chance to find your file.

And you avoid to blow up your search pattern with whitespaces and similar characters.